# Convertir base64 imagen en "input file"

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, base64

Buenos Días,

Estoy realizando un aplicativo en angular que recoge un dibujo realizado en canvas para despues subirlo como imagen png al servidor.

Esta es mi función:

```
$scope.signContract = function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("pwCanvasMain");
    var Sign = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    ContractsFactory.Sign($scope.contratofirma._EntityId, Sign).success(function (data) {

    }).error(function (error) {
        swal("Algo ha ido mal", error.error, "error");
    });
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El caso es que en la petición POST estoy mandado una imagen en base64 y en mi servidor necesito procesarla como una imagen bajo "$_FILE".

¿Existe alguna manera de trasladar el base64 a un input file?

Comment: Creo que de momento una solución por lado del servidor sería esta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153776/convert-base64-string-to-an-image-file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es convertir ese base64 a `Blob` y posteriormente a `File`.

**Ejemplo**

```js
const URL = 'https://api.github.com/gists/8cd4c934fbb98e87d4c99326f609754e'

const getBase64Image = _ => (
  fetch(URL)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(content => content.files['grandma-medium-b64.txt'].content)
);

(async () => {
  try {
    let body = await getBase64Image()
    body = body.split(',')[1]
    const blob = new Blob([atob(body)], {
      type: 'image/jpg',
      encoding: 'utf-8'
    });
    const file = new File([blob], "Grandma on bycle")
    console.log(file)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
})()
```

Comment: Perfecto Gustavo, era exactamente lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias :)